# R Shiny won't show output in the shiny app but only in the console (and how to properly calculate means for a subgroup)?

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I am working on a Shiny App to give feedback to my study participants. I want to give them two pieces of feedback, one text output and one plot output. The plot output is them compared to the sample mean, people of their age and people playing the same sports. This is my server function:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$Gesamtdauer<-eventReactive(
   input$Button, {print(paste("You use media ", Daten[toupper(input$Code), "MN10_01"], "minutes a day.", "That means you use it more than", round(100*(ecdf(Daten[,"MN10_01"])(Daten[toupper(input$Code), "MN10_01"])),0), "percent of the sample."))}
  )
  output$PlotM <- eventReactive(
    input$Button, {
      barplot(unlist(
        list(
          "Du" = as.numeric(as.character(Daten[toupper(input$Code), "MN10_01"])),
          "Ref1" = 65,
          "Overallmean"= mean (as.numeric(as.character (Daten$MN10_01)))
          "sportmean" = 
          mean(
           as.numeric(as.character(Daten$MN10_01[Daten$SP03_01== Daten[toupper(input$Code), "SP03_01"]]))), 
          "agemean"= 
          mean(
           as.numeric(as.character(Daten$MN10_01[Daten$SP01_01 == Daten[toupper(input$Code), "SP01_01"]])))
        )
        ))
                        }
    )
 

}
```

However I got two problems. First, calculating the group means doesn't work. It returns NA every time. I thought it  might be a NA value issue but removing NA didn't fix the issue. So there will not be a plot in the app, but the text output works just fine. If I take the group means out though, R will create both the plot and the text output in the console but won't show any of the two in the app anymore. Can anyone tell me how to get a valid group mean and why Shiny will not show any output in the app anymore as soon as the plot is correct enough to be generated in the console?

SP_01_01 = Age, SP_01_03 and MN is media usage.
Down below is the whole code for context.

```
library (shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library (fresh)
library (ggplot2)

setwd("C:\\Users\\Sportpsychologie_Hk3\\Documents\\Digimed\\APP")

Daten <- read.csv("Daten2.csv", header= TRUE, sep = ";", na.strings=c("",".","NA"), skipNul = TRUE)

rownames (Daten)= make.unique(toupper(Daten$IN04_05))

print(rownames(Daten))
#change rownames back to not having an X
#Change all Codes to Uppercase


#predefine body
body <-  dashboardBody(use_theme(mytheme),
  fluidRow(
    box(      title = "Mediennutzung", background = "green", solidHeader = TRUE, height=300,
              textOutput(outputId = "Gesamtdauer")
              
    ),
    box(background = "green", "Box content", 
      plotOutput(outputId= "PlotM"), 
        height= 300)
  ),
  
  fluidRow(
    box(
      title = "Schlaf", width = 4, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "success",
      "Box content", height= 300
    ),
    box(
      title = "Vergleich mit anderen", width = 4, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "success",
      "Box content", height= 300
    ),
    box(
      title = "Wohlbefinden", width = 4, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "success",
      "Box content", height= 300
    )
  ),
  
  fluidRow(
    box(
      width = 4, background = "green", title = "Warum ist das wichtig?",
      HTML("Ein gesunder Geist wohnt in einem gesunden KÃ¶rper. Wer genug schlÃ¤ft hat bessere Laune, kann sich besser konzentrieren und ist weniger verletzt oder krank. Nicht zuletzt ist eine gute Erholung natÃ¼rlich auch wichtig fÃ¼r deinen sportlichen Erfolg."), height= 125
    ),
    box(
      title = "Warum ist das wichtig?", width = 4, background = "green",
      "Auf sozialen Medien, aber auch im Alltag vergleichen wir uns immer wieder mit anderen. Das ist relativ normal, aber wenn man Ã¼berall Leute sieht, die scheinbar besser, klÃ¼ger oder sportlicher sind, kann sich das negativ auf den Selbstwert und die Stimmung auswirken und im schlimmsten Fall sogar psychische Erkrankungen begÃ¼nstigen.", height= 125
    ),
    box(
      title = "Warum ist das wichtig?",width = 4, background = "green",
      "Was fÃ¼r eine Frage eigentlich- natÃ¼rlich ist es wichtig, dass es dir gut geht! Weniger Stress und eine bessere Laune helfen dir auÃŸerdem, dich besser zu konzentrieren, dich besser zu erholen und fÃ¶rdern deine kÃ¶rperliche Gesundheit.", height= 125
    )
  ),
  
  fluidRow(
    box(
      width = 4, background = "green", title= "Zusammenhang zur Mediennutzung",
      "A box with a solid black background", height= 125
    ),
    box(
      title = "Zusammenhang zur Mediennutzung", width = 4, background = "green",
      "A box with a solid light-blue background", height= 125
    ),
    box(
      title = "Zusammenhang zur Mediennutzung",width = 4, background = "green",
      "This is the test box", height= 125
    )
  )
)




# hier beginnt die eigentliche App:
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Deine Ergebnisse"),
  dashboardSidebar(textInput(inputId = "Code", label= "Bitte gib hier deinen persÃ¶nlichen Code ein", placeholder= "z.B. 01ABAB01"),
                   actionButton (inputId = "Button", label = "Meine Ergebnisse anzeigen"),
                   HTML("<br> Zur Erinnerung: Dein Code setzt sich folgendermaÃŸen zusammen:")
  ),
 body)



server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$Gesamtdauer<-eventReactive(
   input$Button, {print(paste("Du nutzt digitale Medien insgesamt ", Daten[toupper(input$Code), "MN10_01"], "Minuten am Tag.", "Damit nutzt du digitale Medien mehr als", round(100*(ecdf(Daten[,"MN10_01"])(Daten[toupper(input$Code), "MN10_01"])),0), "Prozent der anderen Teilnehmer:innen."))}
  )
  output$PlotM <- eventReactive(
    input$Button, {
      barplot(unlist(
        list(
          "Du" = as.numeric(as.character(Daten[toupper(input$Code), "MN10_01"])),
          "Ref1" = 65,
          "Ref2"= mean (as.numeric(as.character (Daten$MN10_01)))
          #"Ref1" = 
          #mean(
           #as.numeric(as.character(Daten$MN10_01[Daten$SP03_01== Daten[toupper(input$Code), "SP03_01"]]))), 
          #"#REF"= 
          #mean(
           #as.numeric(as.character(Daten$MN10_01[Daten$SP01_01 == Daten[toupper(input$Code), "SP01_01"]])))
        )
        ))
                        }
    )
 

}


  

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Please try to use `renderPlot()` with `plotOutput`, and `renderText()` with `textOutput()`.  `eventReactive()` is just a reactive object, not an output object.

Comment: But why does the textOutput work just like this (as long as you don't add the plot output )? And where do I put the render function if I still want the output only to appear when my participants press the "Go" button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you did not post a sample data, I use iris to show how it works.  Please modify to your use case.

```
Daten <- iris
Daten$MN10_01 <- iris$Petal.Length

#predefine body
body <-  dashboardBody(# use_theme(mytheme),
                       fluidRow(
                         box(      title = "Mediennutzung", background = "green", solidHeader = TRUE, height=300,
                                   verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "Gesamtdauer")
                                   
                         ),
                         box(background = "green", "Box content", 
                             plotOutput(outputId= "PlotM", height=250), 
                             height= 300)
                       ),
                       
                       fluidRow(
                         box(
                           title = "Schlaf", width = 4, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "success",
                           "Box content", height= 300
                         ),
                         box(
                           title = "Vergleich mit anderen", width = 4, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "success",
                           "Box content", height= 300
                         ),
                         box(
                           title = "Wohlbefinden", width = 4, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "success",
                           "Box content", height= 300
                         )
                       ),
                       
                       fluidRow(
                         box(
                           width = 4, background = "green", title = "Warum ist das wichtig?",
                           HTML("Ein gesunder Geist wohnt in einem gesunden KÃ¶rper. Wer genug schlÃ¤ft hat bessere Laune, kann sich besser konzentrieren und ist weniger verletzt oder krank. Nicht zuletzt ist eine gute Erholung natÃ¼rlich auch wichtig fÃ¼r deinen sportlichen Erfolg."), height= 125
                         ),
                         box(
                           title = "Warum ist das wichtig?", width = 4, background = "green",
                           "Auf sozialen Medien, aber auch im Alltag vergleichen wir uns immer wieder mit anderen. Das ist relativ normal, aber wenn man Ã¼berall Leute sieht, die scheinbar besser, klÃ¼ger oder sportlicher sind, kann sich das negativ auf den Selbstwert und die Stimmung auswirken und im schlimmsten Fall sogar psychische Erkrankungen begÃ¼nstigen.", height= 125
                         ),
                         box(
                           title = "Warum ist das wichtig?",width = 4, background = "green",
                           "Was fÃ¼r eine Frage eigentlich- natÃ¼rlich ist es wichtig, dass es dir gut geht! Weniger Stress und eine bessere Laune helfen dir auÃŸerdem, dich besser zu konzentrieren, dich besser zu erholen und fÃ¶rdern deine kÃ¶rperliche Gesundheit.", height= 125
                         )
                       ),
                       
                       fluidRow(
                         box(
                           width = 4, background = "green", title= "Zusammenhang zur Mediennutzung",
                           "A box with a solid black background", height= 125
                         ),
                         box(
                           title = "Zusammenhang zur Mediennutzung", width = 4, background = "green",
                           "A box with a solid light-blue background", height= 125
                         ),
                         box(
                           title = "Zusammenhang zur Mediennutzung",width = 4, background = "green",
                           "This is the test box", height= 125
                         )
                       )
)




# hier beginnt die eigentliche App:
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Deine Ergebnisse"),
  dashboardSidebar(textInput(inputId = "Code", label= "Bitte gib hier deinen persÃ¶nlichen Code ein", placeholder= "z.B. 01ABAB01"),
                   actionButton (inputId = "Button", label = "Meine Ergebnisse anzeigen"),
                   HTML("<br> Zur Erinnerung: Dein Code setzt sich folgendermaÃŸen zusammen:")
  ),
  body)



server <- function(input, output) {
  
  Gr <- eventReactive(input$Button, {
    req(input$Code)
    paste("Du nutzt digitale Medien insgesamt ", Daten[toupper(input$Code), "MN10_01"], "Minuten am Tag.", 
          "Damit nutzt du digitale Medien mehr als", 
          round(100*(ecdf(Daten[,"MN10_01"])(Daten[toupper(input$Code), "MN10_01"])),0), 
          "Prozent der anderen Teilnehmer:innen." )
  })
  
  output$Gesamtdauer<- renderPrint({
    Gr()
  })
  
  pr <- eventReactive(input$Button, {
    c(
      "Du" = as.numeric(as.character(Daten[toupper(input$Code), "MN10_01"])),
      "Ref1" = 65,
      "Ref2"= mean (as.numeric(as.character (Daten$MN10_01)))
    )
  })
  
  output$PlotM <- renderPlot({
    barplot(pr())
  })

  
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

[image: output]